# requestFocusInaWindow() not Working - What am I doing WRONG?

Tags: focus, setfocus

I saw some documentations about Focus in Java but I didn't understand exactly how this works.

I tried to reproduce my doubts in this short code, where I tried to set focus in textfield2 component. I think I have respected the document's requirements - that says that a component need to be displayable, visible and focusable (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html). So, What am I doing wrong?

```
***
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class WindowForm {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextField textField2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WindowForm window = new WindowForm();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public WindowForm() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        myPanel panel = new myPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 239);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        textField1 = new JTextField("textfield1");
        textField1.setBounds(137, 93, 152, 20);
        panel.add(textField1);
        textField1.setColumns(10);

        textField2 = new JTextField("textfield2");
        textField2.setColumns(10);
        textField2.setBounds(137, 124, 152, 20);
        panel.add(textField2);

        panel.changeFocus();
    }

    public class myPanel extends JPanel{

        public void changeFocus() {
            textField2.setVisible(true);
            textField2.setFocusable(true);
            textField2.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

---

I saw some examples that need to be implemented the **addWindowFocusListener** in the jframe - but I need to apply this solution to a CardLayout JPanel - so, I think this won't work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using requestFocusInWindow inside the actionPerformed block.

Like this:

---

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String command = e.getActionCommand();

```
if(command.equals("btnNext")) {
    cardLayout.show(nextJPanel, "Panel2");
    textField2.requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

}

---

Is there any other solution?